# Adding new schema onto file uploads

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api

I am working with Mongodb Express, React, and Node stack for site. Site has existing file with the schema listed.  I want to add another parameter to schema and know that location.

My issue is after adding new parameter to that collections schema how to connect that so next time something is uploaded from site that will include additional parameter to database in Mongo.

A link to example would be great.  Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can do this through mongodb shell.